# how to allocate array of pointers in cpp?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a cpp program and I want to allocate an array of pointers. the array is holding pointers to type Node which is a generic class i've already implemented. I've tried the following:

```
        Node<int,Song>* songArray = new Node<int,Song>[numOfSongs]();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSongs; ++i) {
            Node<int,Song>* songArray[i] = new Node<int,Song>(i, Song(i, this->artistID));
         }
```

but I get an error saying I don't have operator= (which I did implement for Node).
can anyone advice me on what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want a dynamic array of pointers, then you need a double pointer `Node<int,Song>** songArray = ...`.

Comment: Read more about [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types are all over the place.

```cpp
class Song {
  Song(int i, int artistId);
  Song(Song const& song);
  Song &operator=(Sont const& song);
};

Node<int,Song>** songArray = new Node<int,Song>*[numOfSongs]();
for (int i = 0; i < numOfSongs; ++i) {
  songArray[i] = new Node<int,Song>(i, Song(i, this->artistID));
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you meant to do `new Node<int,Song>*[numOfSongs]`, since you're using a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Be aware of C++ [rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)